# Android Wear sync 'freezes' phone interface

Tags: android-wear

I have an Asus ZenWatch 2 paired with my Nexus 6P. (In the past the same watch was paired with a Moto X (2014) with the same symptom.)

When the watch connects to the phone after having been disconnected (such as by going out of range), it often causes the UI on the phone to freeze for around 15-20 seconds. I.e., the phone doesn't react to touches at all, or at least has a lag of several seconds before reacting. After 20 seconds or so, the phone behaves normally again.

The symptom is similar to how my old Nexus 7 (2012) would behave after the infamous 'slow flash' performance issue reared its ugly head. (Not saying this problem is in any way related; it's just a similar behavior.)

I've tried to see what might be monopolizing the CPU using System Monitor as well as `top` via `adb shell`, but I haven't managed to gather much good information.

Has anybody else experienced this? Any tips on isolating the problem?

Versions:

- Android Wear 1.3.0.2176821
- Android on watch: 5.1.1
- Android on Nexus 6P: 6.0
- Android on Moto X: 5.1.1

Comment: This still happening to you? I'm having an issue where my N6P will freeze and crash, forcing a reboot, and I haven't isolated the cause yet. Could it be that my Moto 360 is crashing my N6P, in your opinion?

Comment: The problem pretty much cleared itself up, presumably with some software update or another. I never found a root cause, so I can't say whether your problem is related, but I'd guess probably not.